# ThreeJS and blender exporting best method

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, exporter

I have an object on blender, a bedroom that i get from here : 
http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/66253

I export it in json format to load it in threejs. But i don't have all the mesh of my bed, only one mesh from all the ones i had selected.

I have all of the bed component when i join the meshs.

But i have a question, can't i have all of my meshs without doing join on blender when i export it to json ?
Or do i have to export all the component one by one?

Here is my loading function :

```
function initMesh() {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/bedroom.json',    function(geometry) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
        scene.add(mesh);
    });
}
```

Here is what i get :

[image: Blender picture]

[image: ThreeJS rendering Top]
[image: ThreeJS rendering Bottom]

Thanks

Comment: Did you check "Scene" in the export options?

Comment: I did it after^^. Python script failed, don't know why perhaps because i checked the textures option, without it it works. It's the only way?

Comment: What's the error? I think so... Did you try to select all the parts when exporting?

Comment: yep but always get the last   mesh selected. I will do with the scene add for now. Don't know for the error, forget to register it perhaps because i didn't specify the texture file.

Answer (score 0):

IF you click export with scene, then I think you need load the json using a different loader:

```
THREE.ObjectLoader()
```

also check export materials and embed materials.